# Prevent element from adding attributes

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

Basically the question is in title.

Problem:

Some web sites add classes/ids when you click/hover etc... on it.

Is there a way to prevent this action?

Is there a good way to do that?
After long googling I did not find anything that is well done.

Comment: Not sure it would be possible to disable only this functionality. You could try disabling Javascript altogether, but afaik you cannot disable this functionality when css is used to accomplish it.

Comment: "Some websites" = third-party websites or your own?

Comment: @Vasil I already tried all possible javascript's disable function. In vaine.

Comment: @Diodeus third-party.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use jquery's [off](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.10.2&fn=jQuery.fn.off) to do this:

```
$("*").off("click").off("mouseover").off("hover");
```

That will remove practically every mouse event from the page. It would need to be made into an extension if you want to automatically run it on every page.

Comment: Could you explain who do I need to make it like jquery extension?

Comment: It would need to be a browser extension. You would have to make the extension for your specific browser. Which browser are you using?